# Distributing memory equally (or as fair as possible)

Tags: python, algorithm, math, parallel-processing

I'm doing some parallel programming with Python, MPI and FFTW. I need to distribute a vector of length G equally (or as close to being equally as possible) among N processes. This leads to the following mathematical problem:

Given two integers G, N, where G>N, I want to find the set S of N integers who's sum equals G and where "all the integers are as large as possible".

Examples:

G = 14, N = 3 --> S = {5, 5, 4}

G = 15, N = 3 --> S = {5, 5, 5}

G = 16, N = 3 --> S = {6, 5, 5}

An algorithm to compute S is implemented in FFTW by the function fftw_mpi_local_size. I want to be able to compute this myself though, using Python. That is, I'm in search for an algorithm which solves my problem, or better yet an existing Python function which does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I went about this was to find the smallest value that would evenly be distributed among `N` elements, you can do so using integer division. Then use `%` to find the remainder, and add `1` to that number of elements.

```
def makeValues(G,N):
    val = G//N
    rem = G%N
    return [val]*(N-rem) + [val+1]*rem

>>> makeValues(14,3)
[4, 5, 5]
>>> makeValues(15,3)
[5, 5, 5]
>>> makeValues(16,3)
[5, 5, 6]
```